# JAX-RS JSON Missing Child Object after Marshalling

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I am using Glassfish, EclipseLink, and JAX-RS to provide a REST service that is called from a web site via AngularJS/AJAX. I am returning a JSON object of type `SalesOrder` that has an attribute called `lineItems` of type `List<SalesOrderLine>` annotated with `@OneToMany` on both the attribute property as well as the `getLineItems()` method.

I have successfully called the REST resource and returned a JSON object representing the parent `SalesOrder` object but, even though the server side logs indicate the Response object has a `SalesOrder` entity with (2) `SalesOrderLine` objects, the JSON object on the client/browser side is missing any reference to the child lineItems list or its contents.

```
Glassfish log contents:
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: SalesOrder found with UID: 51
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Number of line items sent back to the REST service with the order is: 2
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Item Quantity is: 10
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Item Quantity is: 5
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response status: 200
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response status info: OK
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response class: class org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response length: -1
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response media type: application/json
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response entity: business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder@2a461205
2015-05-03T18:38:30.480-0600|Info: Response entity number of line items: 2
2015-05-03T18:38:30.481-0600|Info: Response is: OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=200, reason=OK, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}
```

JSON Object on the client/browser side:

```
{
    "salesOrderUid": 51,
    "orderNumber": "1428002042749",
    "billToCity": "Golden",
    "billToFirstName": "Duke",
    "billToLastName": "Developer",
    "billToState": "CO",
    "billToStreetName": "Technology Row",
    "billToStreetNumber": "12345",
    "billToUnitNumber": null,
    "billToZipCode": 80401,
    "creditCardCsv": 123,
    "creditCardExpirationDate": 1483254001000,
    "creditCardNumber": "123456789012",
    "creditCardType": "Visa",
    "emailAddress": "ddeveloper@techexpertconsulting.com",
    "nameOnCreditCard": "Duke Developer",
    "salesOrderDate": 1428002043000,
    "salesOrderStatus": "New",
    "shipToCity": "Golden",
    "shipToState": "CO",
    "shipToStreetName": "Technology Row",
    "shipToStreetNumber": "12345",
    "shipToUnitNumber": null,
    "shipToZipCode": 80401,
    "promoCode": "Test",
    "discount": 5,
    "salesTax": 3.2500000000000001804112415015879378188401460647583007812500,
    "shipping": 10,
    "total": 78.2500000000000001804112415015879378188401460647583007812500
}
```

So it would appear that the marshalling of the Response object is dropping off the child object(s).

Has anyone seen this and figured out how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you by chance add any special serialzation annotations to avoid circular dependency problems? I couldn't reproduce the problem with out any. For instance if I didn't use any annotations, and had a bidirectional relationship, I would simply get an exception (no JSON response) about a circular dependency. This is with MOXy (Glassfish's default JSON provider)

Comment: One way I got it to work without any "ignore" annotations is to use `@XmlID` on the `SalesOrder` id (getter), and `@XmlIDREF` on the `SalesOrder` getter in the `SalesOrderLine` class. This is assuming the you _do_ have a circular dependency. Just made a guess, as you have not shown your classes. If this doesn't help, for further help, please show your classes

Comment: Ahhh, and guessing by looking at your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29607613/2587435), you are using `@XmlTransient` which _would_ cause it not to marshal. If that's the case, the above annotations should fix the problem (just get rid of the `@XmlTransient`)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing from your answer [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson), you've discovered the use of `@XmlTransient` to avoid circular dependencies. The problem with this is that it completely ignores the property when marshalling/unmarshalling.

So how do we fix the problem? Seeing as how you're using Glassfish, which uses MOXy by default for JSON processing, you could simple make use of the [`@XmlID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html) and [`@XmlIDREF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlIDREF.html). Below is what I used to test

```
public class SalesOrder {

    private String id;
    private List<SalesOrderLine> salesOrderItems;

    @XmlID
    public String getId() { return id; }
    ...
}

public class SalesOrderLine {
    private String id;
    private String item;
    private SalesOrder salesOrder;

    @XmlIDREF
    public SalesOrder getSalesOrder() { return salesOrder; }
    ...
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSalesOrder() {
    SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder("12345");

    List<SalesOrderLine> salesOrderItems = new ArrayList<>();
    SalesOrderLine line = new SalesOrderLine("123", "item1", salesOrder);
    salesOrderItems.add(line);
    line = new SalesOrderLine("124", "item2", salesOrder);
    salesOrderItems.add(line);

    salesOrder.setSalesOrderItems(salesOrderItems);

    return Response.ok(salesOrder).build();
}
```

And it works fine. The `SalesOrder` id is used as the `salesOrder` value in the `SalesOrderLine` object. Without these annotations, I would get a circular dependency error from MOXy.

**Note:** From what I have tested, this solution works for Jackson also, given the JAXB annotation support module is used.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. Before I saw these I ended up adding the following annotations to my entity classes...which worked, so I haven't tried the @XmlId and @XmlIdRef annotations. Not sure which set would be better (@Xml... vs @Json...)?

On the parent (SalesOrder) entity:
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=SalesOrderLine.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="salesOrder")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List lineItems;

On the child (SalesOrderLine) entity:
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="SALES_ORDER_UID")
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private SalesOrder salesOrder;

That worked but then I ran into a Glassfish bug "Deployment of a basic webapp, 3 classes, fails to respond with a proper serialized JSON response on the first attempt after deployment." Link: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21141
The work-around for the open bug recommends downloading Jackson jars to the Glassfish modules directory and deleting the OSGI cache. I was able to get this working without deleting the cache. My steps were:
1. Stop Glassfish
2. Download the (6) Jackson jars referenced
3. Re-start Glassfish